# Allow users to try the new version of a PHP application

Tags: php, laravel

I have one legacy PHP application and and one new PHP application in Laravel which is a rebuild from the legacy. Before we roll out the new version, we would like to let the users try it out first and get feedbacks.

Is there anyway to allow users to switch to the new version of the website without using a sub-folder? (example: /v2)

I am thinking about using PHP Session to determine if the user is in v1 or v2. So, basically, the users will get prompted if they want to try out the v2. The old application will save that decision in their account in the database, so next time, when they log back into the website, they will use the v2 without making the decision again.

Still, the part which I haven't figured out yet is that how to switch the current user to the new version of the application without sending them to a sub-folder.

Comment: Put the apps on separate vhosts.

Comment: @AlexHowansky sure, but how do I use user selection to switch them to different applications in different vhosts without changing sub domain name or sub folder?

Comment: Separate vhosts implies separate domain names. One app would live at oldapp.foo.com and one would live at newapp.foo.com -- no subdirs at all. If the user says they want to use the new version, push a flag into their session. On page load of the old app, check that flag -- if set, redirect to the new address.

Answer (score -1):

Good idea ...  you will ask user to select v1 or v2 if he selected v1 include v1 else include v2 without creating sub folder or sub domain

Comment: This is probably applicable on a small page, but I believe it will be a big mess to sort out if done in a larger project. Note that I was not the downvoter.